# Unable to start jetty container on Docker cloud

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, docker, jetty, docker-cloud

I try to start a jetty 9 container with my web.war application on docker cloud.
The docker image work well on my computer, but stop after the startup when I run it on docker cloud.
Here are the logs :

```
2016-07-25T06:15:47.715314954Z 2016-07-25 06:15:47.710:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2842ms
2016-07-25T06:15:49.046489560Z 2016-07-25 06:15:49.044:INFO:oejs.SetUIDListener:main: Setting umask=02
2016-07-25T06:15:49.138996816Z 2016-07-25 06:15:49.129:INFO:oejs.SetUIDListener:main: Opened ServerConnector@6108b2d7{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2016-07-25T06:15:49.139810374Z 2016-07-25 06:15:49.139:INFO:oejs.SetUIDListener:main: Setting GID=999
2016-07-25T06:15:49.141398414Z 2016-07-25 06:15:49.140:INFO:oejs.SetUIDListener:main: Setting UID=999
2016-07-25T06:15:49.151743756Z 2016-07-25 06:15:49.151:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.10.v20160621
2016-07-25T06:15:49.259705382Z 2016-07-25 06:15:49.259:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///var/lib/jetty/webapps/] at interval 1
```

My dockerfile :

```
FROM jetty:latest
MAINTAINER Oreste Viron <*************>
COPY target/web.war /var/lib/jetty/webapps/web.war
USER root
RUN chmod a+r /var/lib/jetty/webapps/web.war
```

And my stackfile :

```
appdb:
  image: 'sim/app_db:latest'
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=****
appweb:
  image: 'sim/app_web:latest'
  links:
    - appdb
  ports:
    - '8080:8080'
```

I don't see anything who can help me to know what is wrong.
Is there someone who has any suggestion to help me to find my mistake ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my jetty container doesn't have enought memory to start and crashs miserabily.
I increased the memory of the VM and now it works.